# Random number choosing problem

Tags: probability

We randomly choose a number from a set of $\{1,2,......,n\}$. Event $A$ is that the chosen number is divisible by $2$, event $B$ is that the number is divisible by $5$. Find all $n$ so that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1,2,\dots$ to be solved is the equation $P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ which is: $$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor }{n}\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor }{n}=\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor }{n}$$
Equivalently to be solved is: $$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{n}{5}\right\rfloor =n\left\lfloor \frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$$

Setting $n=10k+r$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, $r\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and $\langle r,k\rangle\neq\langle 0,0\rangle$ the equation can be written as:

$$k\left[5\left\lfloor \frac{r}{5}\right\rfloor +2\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor -r\right]=-\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{r}{5}\right\rfloor$$

If $r\geq5$ then $\left[5\left\lfloor \frac{r}{5}\right\rfloor +2\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor -r\right]>0$
and $-\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{r}{5}\right\rfloor <0$
so there is no solution.

It remains to check the cases $r\in\left\{ 0,1,2,3,4\right\}$

For $r=0$ the equality is true for every positive integer $k$.

For $r\in\left\{2,4\right\} $ the equality is true for every nonnegative integer $k$.

For $r\in\left\{ 1,3\right\} $ the equality is true if and only if $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)=1/2$ if $n$ is even, and $(n-1)/2n$ if n is odd.$( = [n/2]/n)$
$P(B) = [n/5]/n$. Then use condition for independence $P(A).P(B)= P(A \cap B)$ (i.e. divisible by both $2$ and $5$, so divisible by $10$) to find required values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A) = {p\over n}$, $p$ is the number of elements divisible by $2$

$P(B) = {q\over n}$, $q$ is the number of elements divisible by $5$

$P(A$ and $B) = {r\over n}$, $r$ is the number of elements divisible by $10$

Now note that ${pq\over n}$ = $r$ is an integer.

If $p$ is coprime with $n$, this means $q$ is a multiple of $n$ which is impossible.

Hence $p$ is not coprime with $n$, this means $p$ must be even and $n$ must be even because $k$ and $2k+1$ are coprime for all $k$. Now ${p\over n}={1\over 2}$ and hence $q=2r$. So the number of elements divisible by $5$ is exactly two times the number of elements divisible by $10$. Hence we know the last appearance of a multiple of $5$ is a multiple of $10$. This gives us $n$ must be of form $10k,10k+2,10k+4$.

Feasibility of all three options:

$$10k: {p\over n}={1\over 2}, {q\over n}={1\over 5}, {r\over n}={1\over 10}$$

$$10k+2: {p\over n}={1\over 2}, {q\over n}={k\over 5k+1}, {r\over n}={k\over 10k+2}$$

$$10k+4: {p\over n}={1\over 2}, {q\over n}={k\over 5k+2}, {r\over n}={k\over 10k+4}$$

Comment: Two solutions are not mentioned here: $n=1$ and $n=3$.